# Change date and time in UTC to UTC-5h and UTC-6h based on daylight saving in R

Tags: r

I have a column of dates and time in UTC. I would like to convert the date and time corresponding to the time zone: UTC-5h when DST start and UTC-6h when DST end., keeping in mind the daylight saving.

```
Date
2018-06-11 14:48:26 UTC
2018-06-11 14:48:25 UTC
```

I would be glad if anyone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: So, which time zone is this? It's pretty easy to convert from UTC to other time zones of you know their name, see `OlsonNames()`. E.g., you can do `x <- c("2018-06-11 14:48:26 UTC", "2018-06-11 14:48:25 UTC"); x  <- as.POSIXct(x, tz = "UTC"); attr(x, "tzone") <- "Europe/Berlin"`.

Comment: the time zone is mexico city

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c("2018-06-11 14:48:26 UTC", "2018-06-11 14:48:25 UTC")
x <- as.POSIXct(x, tz = "UTC")

#find time zone name
OlsonNames()[grepl("Mexico", OlsonNames())]
#[1] "America/Mexico_City" "Mexico/BajaNorte"    "Mexico/BajaSur"      "Mexico/General"  

#change time zone
attr(x, "tzone") <- "America/Mexico_City"
x
#[1] "2018-06-11 09:48:26 CDT" "2018-06-11 09:48:25 CDT"
```